# Como montar un server simple para guardar datos , Unity

Tags: server

Estoy aprendiendo a usar unity  y he creado una aplicación simple que  guarda los datos de usuario y 2 cosas más, estos datos són los que quiero enviar a un server.
Actualmente en unity estoy usando wwwForm para guardar y enviar los datos a una dirección de server inexistente, con esto no tengo problemas. Mi problema es que no encuentro ningún tutorial bueno sobre como montar un server para poder hacer pruebas (Enviar los datos de usuario
y unas elecciones básicas ) ya que los tutoriales que me encuentro son para crear multiplayer en juegos.
Además, a ser posible, me sería de utilidad hacer simples comprobaciones como cuantos usuarios esta registrados , si ya están registrados, etc... cosas bastante simples vamos .
Si alguien pudiese apuntarme en la dirección adecuada sobre como montar un server de testeo simple y a ser posible gratis lo agradecería.
También me gustaría comprobar si puedo guardar dichos datos en local con el wwwForm en un archivo de texto simple .

Comment: Puedes usar tu equipo local como [servidor http](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_web#Servidor_web_local).